# webrtc - Disable the use of libcmt

Tags: c++, webrtc

I'm using webrtc and I want to avoid using libcmt because an error in linking is reported. This is the error:

```
LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
```

I have read this in common.gypi but I don't know how to perform that because I cannot find where include.gypi is. I'm using the c++ implementation.

```
# Although base/allocator lets you select a heap library via an
# environment variable, the libcmt shim it uses sometimes gets in
# the way.  To disable it entirely, and switch to normal msvcrt, do e.g.
#  'win_use_allocator_shim': 0,
#  'win_release_RuntimeLibrary': 2
# to ~/.gyp/include.gypi, gclient runhooks --force, and do a release build.
'win_use_allocator_shim%': 1, # 1 = shim allocator via libcmt; 0 = msvcrt
```

Anyone knows something about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib in file common.gypi under chromium/src/build